# Lollipop color selector is always red with custom attributes

Tags: android, colors, attributes, selector

Color selector is not working properly in Android Lollipop (I've tried in different devices), is always red instead of the color I specify. It works fine in Nougat, Oreo, Pie...

**The attr:**

```
<resources>
    ...
    <attr name="buttonIconColorEnabled" format="color"/>
    <attr name="buttonIconColorDisabled" format="color"/>
</resources>
```

**The App theme style:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="buttonIconColorEnabled">@color/white</item>
    <item name="buttonIconColorDisabled">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

**The specific button style:**

```
<style name="AppTheme.PositiveButton" parent="AppTheme">
    ...
    <item name="buttonIconColorEnabled">@color/greenDark</item>
    <item name="buttonIconColorDisabled">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

**The color selector:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="?buttonIconColorEnabled" android:state_enabled="true" />
<item android:color="?buttonIconColorDisabled" android:state_enabled="false" />
```

I think it's not a matter of which context I'm using since it is the Activitie's context (androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity)

Is there any way to make this work in Lollipop? Thanks in advance.